# Induced Electric field in static rectangle around the coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I had an exam in Electromagnetism and had this problem to solve. There is a square around a coil with AC current powered on. The question is to calculate induced electric field into the square contour(4 wires). My question is: “Does induced electric field depend on the shape of contour?”, because I draw IEField following square contour instead of circular shape(which should be correct). The problem should be solved using Faraday’s law
[image]

Comment: Welcome su PSE! You should show us the passages you have tried so far to solve the exercise. So people can, in a better way, help you to understand and solve completely  the problem.

Comment: I tried Faraday’s law in integral form. The Left side of equation i integrated along the contour -E*12a, and the right side dB/dt*a^2pi, since the field outside of the coil of infinite length is approaching 0.